# problem while importing a lightroom 5 catalog in lightroom CC(6)

Tags: lightroom-catalog

I just wiped my mac and just made a fresh install. When I do so I usually install a new version of LR and import my old catalog (that is usually converted properly). This time it everything has gone flawlessly until at the end of the import procedure I can't see any folder or picture I had in my old catalog and can't do anything about it. does anybody have a clue of what's happening? Thank you!

Comment: Are the actual image files in the same path?  Can you post a screenshot of your library?

Comment: here it is, the folders are on the same path and the library shows like on the image. https://www.dropbox.com/s/78mdl2pexawjwd1/Schermata%202017-07-15%20alle%2017.16.01.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you do not want to "import" your catalog when moving to a new computer with also having a new version of lightroom, but follow a series of steps to ensure everything is preserved including presets, calibration profiles (if used), etc. A good resource is [here](https://www.lightroomqueen.com/how-move-lightroom-to-new-computer/), but fundamentally you want to find your catalog, photos, presets and templates, and lens/camera profiles (if you created any yourself), and plugins. Move them all to the SAME locations on the new machine.  You do not need to move the preview folder. Then install lightroom on the new machine, and open (not import) the old version catalog. Lightroom will automatically convert it to the new version (leaving the old catalog unchanged).  Since the photos are in the same place (e.g. drive letter) it should locate them.

If having the photos in the same location is not possible (e.g. you must change drive letters), AFTER you let lightroom convert them, go to the folder display and use the context menu to tell Lightroom where each folder is on the new machine.

Note especially that presets on the old machine could be in two different places depending on your choice for the option to store them beside the library (the above pointer explains).

Once all is stable and you get a good backup delete the old format catalog so as not to be confused later (if you open it again it converts again).

What happened with you likely relates in some fashion to the location of the actual images; it may be possible to use the context menu on the folder display on the new machine to find the location of the top level folder(s) and have them found -- assuming the images actually made it to the new machine, did they?  But you should still look into the other things (such as presets and templates) to see if you needed to move them as well. Not everything is saved in the catalog.

Comment: I'm sorry but I probably have been inaccurate. I have done what you're telling me but when opening the old catalog into the new version of Lightroom, after the obvious conversion, I can't find anything showing in my folder display. This is actually the main problem I'm having right now.

so after opening the LR_5 catalog into LR_CC, my folder display part is empty.

Comment: Does the folder tab display and is empty, or are you not getting the panel at all?  Did the catalog (from LR5, right?) you opened go through a conversion process; it should have prompted.  The new catalog will get a new name (usually ending in -2 or similar), do you see both old and new catalog?  My GUESS is you are seeing only a new, default catalog, and not your old catalog; hunt out the actual catalogs (*.lrcat) and see if you can figure out what happened.

Comment: the folder tab displays and it's empty. The catalog from LR_5 has gone through a conversion process. I see both catalogs (a new one has been created and opened after conversion) here's a screenshot, sorry about the Italian localization, but I guess it's pretty similar. https://www.dropbox.com/s/78mdl2pexawjwd1/Schermata%202017-07-15%20alle%2017.16.01.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you SURE that the catalog you have open is the one that converted?  Look in Edit, Catalog Preferences, General.  Is the drive name/letter the exact same as it was on the old computer, if not try changing it so it matches and re-open lightroom.

Comment: It is, and I'm totally sure. I also have tried again and the result is identical. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yply7mivzw6c87/Schermata%202017-07-15%20alle%2017.58.35.png?dl=0

Comment: Notice it's empty (tiny), but has a -2 name.  My guess is your old system had a default catalog in the default position that was empty, and the original catalog was somewhere else under some other name.  The default was moved over (empty) and converted (hence the -2; if LR had just created it upon installation with the new version, no -2).  And empty is what you see now.  You need to find the old catalog.  I respect that you are totally sure, but I suggest something you do not understand happened and that is not it.

Comment: I'm not getting offended about this, I'm here to figure out what happened and I really appreciate your help :) I have considered this option and I will have another look to search for other catalogs around my TimeMachine backup. Unfortunately, the way files are stored doesn't help that much. I'll let you know ASAP.

Comment: possibly useful reference: https://www.lightroomqueen.com/articles-page/lightroom-cc6-default-locations/